# Create a function to change text color

Tags: jquery

I have this function

```
function example() {
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;
    var minus = a - b;

    if (a > b) {
        $('#result').html('+' + minus);
        $('#result').css('color', 'Red')
    }
}
```

I've updated my code to the below, but it isn't working properly.

```
function calcul(x, y) {
    var x;
    var y;
    var minus = x - y;
    if (x > y) {
        $('#result').html('+' + minus);
        $('#result').css('color', 'Red')
    }
}

function example() {
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;

    calcul(a, b);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're *re-declaring* `x` and `y` in the function, but not setting them to any values:

```
var x;
var y;
```

So for the rest of the function, `x` and `y` are undefined.  Simply don't re-declare them like that.  Remove those two lines.